# Why does jvm throw ExceptionInitializerError even when the static block gets what it requests?

Tags: exception

I have a JSF application that's having just one button "searchparty" on the welcome page. When it's clicked, the process goes to a static block and its referring to an "ecore" file. I have that file in the classpath of the subproject, yet, it's not able to detect it. I'm stuck here. I've also updated the JVM classpath in WAS 7.0 with the jars of subprojects.

Is there any way I can get this reference to get detected?

```
{3:21:903 EDT] 00000026 ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [DS-App] [/CustomerDataStewardshipWeb] [/navigationVertical.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[7/22/14 11:13:24:519 EDT] 00000028 application   E   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(RequestPhaseListener.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:222)
    at com.ibm.mdm.ui.base.CommonModel.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:167)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1549)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:88)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at com.ibm.faces.databind.SelectItemsVarResolver.resolveVariable(SelectItemsVarResolver.java:38)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.getParty(NavigationVertical.java:547)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.cleanPartyData(NavigationVertical.java:462)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.cleanSessionStates(NavigationVertical.java:438)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.doMenuItemToSession4a(NavigationVertical.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: admin.ecore
    at com.dwl.admin.impl.AdminPackageImpl.loadPackage(Unknown Source)
    at com.dwl.admin.impl.AdminPackageImpl.init(Unknown Source)
    at com.dwl.admin.AdminPackage.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    ... 71 more

[7/22/14 11:13:24:538 EDT] 00000028 lifecycle     W   JSF1053: (Listener: com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(), Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1,  View ID: /navigationVertical.jsp) Exception thrown during phase-listener execution: javax.faces.FacesException: #{pc_NavigationVertical.doMenuItemToSession4a}: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
[7/22/14 11:13:24:541 EDT] 00000028 lifecycle     W   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(RequestPhaseListener.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3954)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:945)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)

[7/22/14 11:13:38:039 EDT] 0000002a ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [DS-App] [/CustomerDataStewardshipWeb] [/viewAbout.jsp]: Initialization successful.
[7/22/14 11:13:38:059 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O DEBUG: PageCodeBase - The matching locale= en
[7/22/14 11:13:38:060 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O DEBUG: PageCodeBase - The browser locale= en_US
[7/22/14 11:13:38:060 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en__.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:38:061 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en_.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:38:061 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:50:823 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O DEBUG: PageCodeBase - The matching locale= en
[7/22/14 11:13:50:823 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O DEBUG: PageCodeBase - The browser locale= en_US
[7/22/14 11:13:50:824 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en__.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:50:824 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en_.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:50:824 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O /images/IMDMS_v9-0_en.gif||null
[7/22/14 11:13:58:149 EDT] 00000026 SystemOut     O DEBUG: BaseDataStewardship - userGroupImpl is: com.ibm.mdm.ui.registry.WASUserGroupImpl
[7/22/14 11:13:58:174 EDT] 0000002a SystemOut     O DEBUG: BaseDataStewardship - userGroupImpl is: com.ibm.mdm.ui.registry.WASUserGroupImpl
[7/22/14 11:14:07:816 EDT] 0000002a application   E   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dwl.datastewardship.model.Party (initialization failure)
                                 javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dwl.datastewardship.model.Party (initialization failure)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(RequestPhaseListener.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
    at com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dwl.datastewardship.model.Party (initialization failure)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:140)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1549)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:107)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:374)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:222)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:88)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ChainAwareVariableResolver.resolveVariable(ChainAwareVariableResolver.java:107)
    at com.ibm.faces.databind.SelectItemsVarResolver.resolveVariable(SelectItemsVarResolver.java:38)
    at com.sun.faces.el.VariableResolverChainWrapper.getValue(VariableResolverChainWrapper.java:112)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:143)
    at com.sun.faces.el.FacesCompositeELResolver.getValue(FacesCompositeELResolver.java:73)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:45)
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:263)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.getValue(ValueBindingValueExpressionAdapter.java:113)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.getParty(NavigationVertical.java:547)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.cleanPartyData(NavigationVertical.java:462)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.cleanSessionStates(NavigationVertical.java:438)
    at pagecode.NavigationVertical.doMenuItemToSession4a(NavigationVertical.java:378)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:159)
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:276)
    at com.sun.faces.application.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 37 more

[7/22/14 11:14:07:829 EDT] 0000002a lifecycle     W   JSF1053: (Listener: com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(), Phase ID: RESTORE_VIEW 1,  View ID: /navigationVertical.jsp) Exception thrown during phase-listener execution: javax.faces.FacesException: #{pc_NavigationVertical.doMenuItemToSession4a}: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dwl.datastewardship.model.Party (initialization failure)
[7/22/14 11:14:07:833 EDT] 0000002a lifecycle     W   com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
com.ibm.faces.webapp.RequestPhaseListener.afterPhase(RequestPhaseListener.java:101)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleAfterPhase(Phase.java:175)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:114)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:104)
com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:265)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:149)
com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.SessionFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
com.ibm.mdm.ui.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:125)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:507)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:878)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:191)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:453)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:515)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:306)
com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:84)
com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1656)
}
```

Comment: The error occurs because class admin.encore cannot be found.

Comment: The problem is occurring in the class initialization sequence for com.dwl.admin.AdminPackage.  Specifically, the AdminPackage static initializer called com.dwl.admin.impl.AdminPackageImpl.init which called its own loadPackage method.  Presumably AdminPackage was asking for admin.encore to be found and loaded.  One would guess that there's a "path" (likely different from `classpath`) that AdminPackage is using to resolve its references.  That's about as far as I can go on this, without knowing anything of the particular products involved.

Comment: (There is a minor point to note:  The use of "AdminPackageImpl" implies that AdminPackage itself is something of a "factory", so it's vaguely possible that it should instead be loading a *different* implementation from "AdminPackageImpl", but a config parm has mucked things up.  Just to confuse things more.)

Answer (score 0):

Precisely where/how is "encore" in your classpath?

Comment: The ecore is in a subproject called SDO(not the full name but just for our discussion to be easier)

the Web project is referring to the SDO . The webproject obviously doesn't have a .classpath but the SDO does. While compiling and building SDO, I put the ecore directory in the .classpath of the SDO and I have the SDO.jar in the classpth of the JVM on Websphere App Server.

Comment: SDO has src and model directories. 
model has the ecore

Comment: And what is the contents of SDO.jar?

Comment: Where in the jar is the "admin" directory?

Comment: If I list the contents of the jar I should see `admin/encore.class` as one of the members.

Comment: SDO.jar has bin, com, META-INF , model , src and a .classpath. The AdminPackage.java is in com.dwl.admin . It's calling another calss called CommonModel.java which has the static block. CommonModel.java is in com.ibm.mdm.ui.base in CommonUI (a different subproject just like the SDO)

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't been clear. "admin.ecore" is one file. It's an ecore file. This ecore file is in model directory in SDO project. SDO has 2 directories which are model (has all ecore files) and src(has java files)

Comment: In the SDO classpath I have given the classpath entry: 

        <classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="model"/>

Comment: Well, it's not found.  Or if it is found, in `catch` handler, the exception is being rethrown for some reason.

Comment: I'm not getting this error in my Local machine (built by eclipse) . This is only in DEV where I built on Jenkins with an ant script

Comment: Hot Licks , I have one question . Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Missing serialized package: admin.ecore

Since the webproject doesnt have a classpath, is there an equivalent where we can mention this?

Comment: The exception trace is pretty clear -- com.dwl.admin.impl.AdminPackageImpl.loadPackage is throwing the RuntimeError, and it's not being handled.  The exception occurs within the class initializer com.ibm.mdm.ui.base.CommonModel.<clinit>, so that cascades to "ExceptionInInitializerError".  The stuff further down in your listing is confusing -- it appears to be later exceptions due to the earlier ones, but it's a little too garbled to say for sure.

Comment: I'm not familiar with JSF or whatever, so I can't say where the code would be looking for the file.

Comment: Thanks Hot Licks, I'll try debugging this from our discussion and will keep this thread posted.

Comment: (Sorry for my confusion. I got confused because there is a NoClassDefFoundError farther down, but that's referencing com.dwl.datastewardship.model.Party.)

Comment: I still am not able to figure out the issue. I added the jars to Claspath, WEB-INF/lib, I even put the ecore file it's looking for inside the WEB-INF/lib, but still its throwing the same issue. Do you think it's an issue with the WAS JDK?